# How can I get IAP receipt If user uninstall the app and install it again? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase

If I purchase something and check the purchase receipt I can get the encoded value of it by this:

```
if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
            FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

            do {
                let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                print(receiptData)

                let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                print("receiptString \(receiptString)")
                // Read receiptData
            }
            catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
        }
```

But If I purchase something, then delete the app and reinstall it again and check the receipt, I can't get anything with the upper code. It just get the `appStoreReceiptURL`  and go straight away without entering `do {} catch`. How can I get the receipt in this scenario?

Comment: You should provide a "Restore purchases" button

Comment: @Paulw11 If I use restore purchase, then user will get back the amount for his last purchase right? But here I want to check If his payment time span is still valid or not valid. If it's valid I will let him enter into my app, if not then he will stay. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to restore purchase , the user **will not be refunded** the purchased amount, however you would be able to verify that user purchased the product, and will also receive receipt that contants all the information about his previous purchase, therefore you can safely verify the purchase in your App.

In App Store Review Guides is clearly stated that

> Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may
> not expire, and you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for
> any restorable in-app purchases.

That means you should provide some mechanism (e.g. Restore Purchase Button) anyway, regardless of scenario when the user uninstalls Application. In your case, you can provide the Restore button directly on your Login screen. Check some inspiration on Restore purchase button in [Apple Human Interface guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/in-app-purchase/overview/auto-renewable-subscriptions/)

I you want to restore purchase directly with Apple API after user taps the Restore Purchase button, you can use:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

,which triggers Apple servers, checks the users Apple ID and gets all of the app purchases they have made before and returns you transaction that you observe with `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` with this code:

```
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        if transaction.transactionState == .restored {
            //here is your restored transaction
        }
    }
}
```

If you however want to get hold of the new receipt with all receipt data, including previous purchases, I recommend not using directly Apple API, but using `SwiftyStoreKit` library : [link on github](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) . Code example below:

```
    func restoreYourPurchases( completion: @escaping (Result<Bool,Error>) -> Void) {
    SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true) { results in
        var restoreSuccessfull = false
        if results.restoreFailedPurchases.count > 0 {
            print("Restore Failed: \(results.restoreFailedPurchases)")
        }
        else if results.restoredPurchases.count > 0 {
            print("Restore Success: \(results.restoredPurchases)")
            for purchase in results.restoredPurchases {
                if purchase.productId == "yourID" {
                    let timeOfPurchase = purchase.originalPurchaseDate
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Nothing to Restore")
            completion(.success(false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice explanation. I was confused about the functionality of "Restore Button". I thought, It is used to refund users money but actually It just ensures that the user purchase the service previously If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Talking about `SwiftyStoreKit`, I saw a lot of App rejection messages on their Girhub discussion tab. Do you think I should use that third party?

Comment: Well, I have implemented `SwiftyStoreKit` myself about 6 months ago and faced no problems with App Store submission, however things might have changed.. You can still use basic `StoreKit`  if you want. Or use some combination -> `StoreKit` for purchases (fairly easy) and `SwiftyStoreKit` for restoring and retrieving original purchase data.

Comment: I have one more question regarding Restore Purchase. I tried Restore Purchase with different App ID on different device and It works perfectly (Giving all purchased history by product ID) But as you know Restore purchase works for "Non-consumable" & "Auto Renewable" only, so If I want to implement Restore purchase for "Consumable" or "Non Renewing" purchase, how can I achieve that? @Mr.SwiftOak

Comment: well, right now I am not sure how to restore consumables ( and if it is possible via Apple API) , as I have not implemented those. However what you can do is also keeping track of purchased goods on firebase server, which I also do and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I found out It's way less complex to track the record in own server. By the way do you know how can someone gets the "Introductory Offers time length" (Free Trial) in Auto Renewable subscription? Thanks again. @Mr.SwiftOak

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot help with this as I have not implemented it. Wish you luck though!

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot for your feedback. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have done the receipt validation by communicating directly from my app to App Store server with the help of App Specific secrete key. But I have couple of queries. I posted a new question regarding this. Can you please take have a look on it? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985272/whats-the-use-of-transaction-in-updatedtransactions-delegate-method-for-in